# In Abrahamic religions, what is the origin of angels?

Tags: origins, abrahamic-religions, angels

In Abrahamic religions (Judaism, Islam, Christianity, and potentially by relation Zoroastrianism), what do the sources say is the origin of angels?

Comment: This makes me think of https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Genesis-6-2/ but from the script it is neither clear (to me, at least) where the "sons of good" came from, nor if they have any relation with the *angels*, nor if their offspring has. Ans I joined this community just for the above question.

Answer (score 5):

There is no specific myth of the origin of angels in mainstream Christianity or Judaism, but more apocryphal stuff abounds. The closest you'll get in the Bible proper is [Psalm 148](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20148), where Yahweh creates angels along with all heavenly things "by his command." It's probably as simple as that - no unusual origin like with man, just say it and it is so. It does, however, establish a very "otherworldly" even "celestial" nature to them, since they're named with the sun, moon, and stars. No terrestrial beings or features are mentioned here.

Jewish Midrashic and Talmudic literature has angels created on the fifth day:

> he Talmud and Midrash contain a variety of opinions on the origin and nature of angels. The angels were created on the second or the fifth day of creation (R. Johanan and R. Ḥanina, Gen. R. 1:3 and parall.; S.A. Wertheimer, Battei Midrashot, 1 (19502), 25; cf. also R. Kirchheim in Oẓar Neḥmad, 3 (1860), 59, ed. J. Blumenfeld). Creation of angels is continuous since every pronouncement by God results in the creation of angels. Angels walk upright, speak Hebrew, and are endowed with understanding; they can fly in the air, move from one end of the world to another, and foretell the future (Ḥag. 16a). Thus angels have something in common with both men and demons. They have the shape of man, but consist half of fire and half of water (TJ, RH 2; PdRK, ed. Mandelbaum, 6; Song R. 3:11, 15).

http://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/Judaism/angels.html

Answer (score -2):

Well, in Christianity,

> For by [God] all things were created.(1 Colossians 1:16)

If God created everything, God created angels.

I don't know about Judiasm, or Islam, but one Abrahamic faith should speak for all three.

Comment: As for any Abrahamic religion, anything that *is* is created by the respective god, your answer does not add any information. Eve, for example, was not simply created "from scratch" but from a rib of Adam. Though your statement is true,  it is far from being an answer.

Comment: Adam was created by God. If something is created from another thing created, then you can definitely say that the 1st thing is created by the creator. But I will add to my answer.

Comment: @_bleh obviously so, but this does not add any understanding to the first question.

Comment: I'm thinking.... lol

Comment: @_bleh "I'm thinking.... lol" :-) According to Quran, man was created from a clot of blood (translation disputable). My point is that the OP  is looking for more information than just "everything is created by THE CREATOR".

Comment: Ik just a bit busy. You'll get your quality answer soon.

Comment: @_bleh now hurries, quality weighs above quantity, and, in this case, above instancy .

Comment: Maybe like, 6 hours. Write your own answer if you want to! or; edit my answer.

Comment: @_bleh 6 hoers or 60 ... take your time; and if I was sure to have a perfect answer of my own, I would have posted it already instead of just nagging you. Still searching.

Comment: @_bleh it has been far more than 6 hours now waiting for your response. Downvoting.